# How to disable Html.RadioButtonFor in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

This is my Html.RadioButtonFor

```
 <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Account, Account.A1)<label for="Account"></label>A</label>
 <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Account, Account.A2)<label for="Account"></label>B</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `prop` in jQuery as well.

```
$('input[name=ticketID]').prop("disabled",true);
```

You can also use `toggleDisabled` as generalized function in your code.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            this.disabled = !this.disabled;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
$('button').click(function(){
  $('input[name=ticketID]').toggleDisabled();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="ticketID"/>Radio
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery here, you can pass the value as html attribute in RadioButtonFor method:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Account, Account.A1, new {disabled = "disabled"} )
```

Comment: He has asked from jQuery dude.

Comment: @Loading..: whats the point of making things complicated when can be achieved using adding simple attribute.

Comment: It's not about the complexity, it's about the question. Asked from Jquery only.